# How can I input value in the each input field?

Tags: cypress

HTML:

```
<!-- Block 1-->
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <span>Type</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iput class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" placeholder="Input value"></iput>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Block 2-->
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <span>Type</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iput placeholder="Input value"></iput>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Block ..N -->
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <span>Type</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iput placeholder="Input value"></iput>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  cy.contains('div', 'Type')
    .next()
    .find('div')
    .eq(i)     
    .click({ multiple: true })

  cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')
    .eq(i)
    .type(`value ${i}`)
}
```

There are many bloks with input field for each.
I want to input value for each.
I make cycle but value is inputted only in the first input value. How can I solve this for each input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      cy.get('*[class^="row "]')
        .eq(i)
        .contains('div', 'Type')
        .next()
        .find('div')
        .eq(i)
        .click({ multiple: true });

    cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')
      .eq(i)
      .type(`value ${i}`)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find all instances of the elements and [then use `.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) to iterate over them.

```
cy.contains('div', 'Type')
  .each(($el, index) => {
    cy.wrap($el).siblings('div').click();
    cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item').eq(index).type(`value ${index}`);
})
```

Comment: the value is entered only in the first input

Comment: Do you have a separate list of inputs that you want to use? Or are there multiple values return from `.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item`? If so, you can use an `.each()` on that `get` as well. I'll update my answer if that's the case.

Comment: The value is inputted in the first input field each times of the circle

Comment: So you want to iterate over each `.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item` that you find?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is the input element `<input placeholder="Input value"></input>`, you can directly apply `each` on this. I will consider `input` as the selector as I don't have the exact HTML.

```js
cy.get('input').each(($ele, index) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).type(`value ${index}`)
})
```

Comment: Your code is like previous answer and it doesn't work

Comment: The code that I wrote is based on an assumption that I mentioned in the Answer. To get an exact answer, please add the exact HTML of the page and also mention what kind of error you are getting.

Comment: I don't receive error. I have problem that value was inputted ONLY in the first input field each loop

Comment: add the exact HTML of the page

Comment: This HTML is exact without differen 'div' blocks without classes

Comment: My code doesn't require divs. It directly iterates on the input field. So if the code as you mention in the question is exactly similar to the original HTML than the above code should work perfectly

Comment: ,I'm sorry, Iforgot paste class 'ant-select-dropdown-menu-item' in the HTML, You are right and I have edited it.